# Add-Migration fails on WinUI3 while using GenericHost pattern

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, winui-3

Previously I have used different patterns to make `Add-Migration` works. `Design-Time` factory works fine for me in `WinUI3`.

but later on we added `GenericHost` to our `WinUI3` app.

I've tried to remove these `Design-Time` factories and follow `Application Service` pattern. because it works with my configurations while `Design-Time` factory doesn't. So I don't needed to hard-code my `ConnectionStrings` in the code base.

But I'm getting this error when I'm running `Add-Migration`:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing
> without the application service provider. Error: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll'
> or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

> Unable to create an object of type 'BusinessDomainContext'. For the different patterns  supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

here is my command:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate2 -Context BusinessDomainContext -OutputDir Migrations\BusinessDomain
```

I don't understand the source of this problem.

At the next step I've tried to add below config to my `*.csproj`. Error got solved:

```
<WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
```

But **Nothing happened after that**.
Using `--verbose` I've got this logs:

```
 Using project directory 'D:\...' Remaining arguments: .
 Finding DbContext classes...
 Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
 Finding application service provider in assembly 'DesktopApplication'...
 Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
 Using environment 'Development'.
```

At the next step I have tried to `DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_MAIN` by updating `*.csproj` file.

```
    <DefineConstants>DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_MAIN</DefineConstants>
```

I have added new `Program.cs` file. with this content:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
    => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

// EF Core uses this method at design time to access the DbContext
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
=> Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureServices(services=>
{
    services.AddDbContext<BusinessDomainContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aa.BusinessDomain;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
    });
});
```

For me, I looks terrific, But it works.
There is an open Issue [for this](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7068) which is open from 2022. and the thing I've done looks bad. I think `Microsoft` should release `WinUI3` in compatible form. I should not re-invent things to getting it to work.